# Trying to create simple menu in auction service page, have some problems

Tags: html, css, layout, menu

I'm trying to create a simple layout for auction service page, where you can use only limited functions from html. I'm trying to set 4 buttons (image link) in one line using css but cant achieve that. Instead I have a "stairs".

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: in addition to the answers below, change this line <center>{description}</center> to <div id="center">info here</div> and add this to the css #center { text-align: center; }

Comment: Please avoid the use of links to images, upload the image itself so that the questions doesn't become useless if URL is unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `display: inline-block` in the CSS to get all your buttons in a row.

You could also use [`<input type="image"`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) in your HTML. And for accessibility, you will need to provide a text alternative to the background images.

**HTML**

```
<input type="image" class="inarow" src="img_submit.gif" alt="Submit"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.inarow {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your links are block level elements, specified in the styles as display: block. In order to have them aligned in the same line you either need to add float left to the links, or change display block to display: inline-block (inline).

**Example CSS for your HTML code**

```
.sale, . obuwie, . portfele, . torebki { display: inline-block; }
```

**OR**

```
.sale, . obuwie, . portfele, . torebki { float: left; display: block; }
#odsylacz1 { clear: both; }
```

I would as well suggest you to clean a bit the whole code, and maybe use images inside links.

Hope this helps